# JS popup does't works comparison operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 link and mini preview photo and url 3 links its good link opsss and upsss is wrong when i click good link i'm going to new page when i click error link attr href change to adresError and then we have popup This only works for the first time second time click all links have a popup and should have only opsss and upsss

http://jsfiddle.net/3ptktp47/1/

Here is my code :

```
var nameError = [
            "opsss",
            "upsss",
            ];
$(function() {  
    $('#prev').hide();
    $(function() { 
        var title_link = 'kliknij aby podejżeć';
        $(".preview-link a")
            .attr({title: title_link})
            //.tooltip()
            .click(function(){

            $('.preview-link a img').css('opacity',1);


            var sciezka = $(this).attr("href");
            var tytul = $(this).attr("title");
            var adres = $(this).text();
            //alert(adres);
            $(".duzy").attr({ src: sciezka, alt: tytul, style:'cursor:pointer;', href:'http://www.'+ adres,'target':'_blank'});
            $('.link').html(adres).attr({href:'http://www.'+ adres,'target':'_blank'});
            $('#prev').show();


            function errorDomain() {
                $('.link, .duzy').removeAttr('href');
                $('.link, .duzy').click(function(event){
                    $('#popup, .popup-bg').show('slow');
                    $('.server_url').html(adresError).attr({href:'http://'+ adresError,'target':'_blank'});
                });

            };

                if(adres == 'opsss.com'){
                    var adresError = 'x4ql.nazwa.pl/'+ nameError[0];
                    errorDomain();
                }else if(adres == 'upsss.com' ){
                    var adresError = 'x4ql.nazwa.pl/'+ nameError[1];
                    errorDomain();
                }else{
                    //$('#popup, .popup-bg').fadeOut();
                };


                $('.cancel, .popup-bg').click(function(event){
                    $('#popup, .popup-bg').fadeOut();
                });

            return false;
        });



        $('.close').click(function(){
            $('#prev').hide();
        });
        $('.link').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).css({style: 'color:#000;'});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what this issue is here.  Could you explain what is going wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I have 5 link and mini preview photo and url

3 links its good link opsss and upsss is wrong when i click good link i'm going to new page when i click error link attr href change to adresError and then we have popup This only works for the first time

second time click all links have a popup and should have only opsss and upsss

Comment: @martex Punctuation, dude...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**
Ok, I was able to handle your problem.

Your `.click()` event in the `errorDomain()` method was firing every time you clicked this square. I managed it to toggle a class on `a.duzy` element with `toggleClass('error')` in your `if-statement` where you check the address.
Inside your `click()` event, a `if-statement` is checking if the `.duzy` element has class named `error` with `hasClass('error')` , this has following result -

`TRUE`- your popup will be displayed

`FALSE` - nothing happens

I hope my answer is clear enough, but please check out the **edited** fiddle.

**EDITED SOURCE**:

Your `errorDomain()` Method

```
function errorDomain() {
  $('.link, .duzy').removeAttr('href');
   $('.duzy, .link').click(function (event) {
      if ($(this).hasClass("error")) {
          $('#popup, .popup-bg').show('slow');
             $('.server_url').html(adresError).attr({
                href: 'http://' + adresError,
                'target': '_blank'
             });
          }
   });
}
```

The `if-statements`

```
if (adres == 'opsss.com') {
    var adresError = 'x4ql.nazwa.pl/' + nameError[0];
    $('a.duzy').toggleClass("error");
    errorDomain();
} else if (adres == 'upsss.com') {
    var adresError = 'x4ql.nazwa.pl/' + nameError[1];
    $('a.duzy').toggleClass("error");
    errorDomain();
} else {
    $('a.duzy').removeClass("error");
}
```

[Edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0op7p81/1/)

Comment: I have 5 link and mini preview photo and url

3 links its good link opsss and upsss is wrong when i click good link i'm going to new page when i click error link attr href change to adresError and then we have popup This only works for the first time

second time click all links have a popup and should have only opsss and upsss

Comment: Great
this is what I meant :)